# Why does my eclipse fail to start android virtual device, when the files are there?

Tags: android, eclipse

When trying to start up my Android AVD emulator, I get the following error message in eclipse

```
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/james/development/tools/android//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

However, the file is clearly there as displayed below

```
james@nevada:~/development/tools/android/tools$ pwd
/home/james/development/tools/android/tools
james@nevada:~/development/tools/android/tools$ ls -l
total 9504
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james  341773 2010-05-07 19:47 adb
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james    3636 2010-05-07 19:47 android
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james    2382 2010-05-07 19:47 apkbuilder
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james    3265 2010-05-07 19:47 ddms
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james   89032 2010-05-07 19:47 dmtracedump
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james    1940 2010-05-07 19:47 draw9patch
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james 6886136 2010-05-07 19:47 emulator
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james  478199 2010-05-07 19:47 etc1tool
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james    1987 2010-05-07 19:47 hierarchyviewer
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james   23044 2010-05-07 19:47 hprof-conv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james    1939 2010-05-07 19:47 layoutopt
drwxrwxr-x 4 james james    4096 2010-05-07 19:48 lib
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james   16550 2010-05-07 19:47 mksdcard
-rw-rw-r-- 1 james james  205851 2010-05-07 19:48 NOTICE.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 james james      33 2010-05-07 19:47 source.properties
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james 1447936 2010-05-07 19:47 sqlite3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james    3044 2010-05-07 19:47 traceview
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james  187965 2010-05-07 19:47 zipalign
```

Any ideas why I may be getting this error? I was able to run my AVD yesterday, the only thing I have done since then is to restart the box (VirtualBox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a double `/` in your path. I'm not sure if that's causing the problem though

`/tools/android//tools/emulator`

Comment: the double \\ shouldnt matter? Since I can cd using that path